# Clover - getting coverage without automated tests

Tags: java, code-coverage, clover

I am currently exploring various code coverage tools for use in project and short listed on
clover amongst clover, Emma and cobertura. ( My org is ready to pay for clover and its nice )

But we donot have automated tests. all tests are manual and we need results to be generated run time using instrumented code.

clover's [wiki's](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/About+Code+Coverage) inital lines say

> Code coverage is the percentage of code which is covered by automated
>   tests.

Can clover collect coverage on non-automated tests ? i.e the requirement is i instrument code at compile time and get coverage report when i actually run the code. 
Googled much but could not find most appropriate answer.

Are there alternatives to achieve that if clover does not support it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are manual steps which clover website [documents](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Clover+Command+Line+Tools). probably using this we can achieve.. but not sure of exact optimal way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of coverage tools is to instrument the application code so that when it's run, statistics are collected, and finally written into reports. Wether the application code is run by automated tests or by manual tests doesn't matter. It will work with manual tests, but be of course much longer.

Comment: Correct. I understand that. Any idea on how to achieve that using clover ? I'm using maven-clover2-plugin. Any  pointers on how to achieve this ?

Comment: In order to measure coverage from manual tests, just instrument the code with Clover and run your application ensuring that the Clover runtime JAR (com.cenqua.clover:clover) is available in the class path.